# Avro Tools - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub, avro-tools

I follow this doc [Capture streaming events - Azure Event Hubs | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview) to use Avro Tools in Windows Server 2012 R2. I get below error message, screenshot:
[image: Could not locate executable winutils]

> 20/03/31 13:31:24 ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils
> binary in the hadoop binary path java.io.IOException: Could not locate
> executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.  at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:382)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:397)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.(Shell.java:390)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.(StringUtils.java:80)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.(FileSystem.java:2820)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.(FileSystem.java:2816)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2682)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:372)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:171)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:356)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)    at
> org.apache.avro.mapred.FsInput.(FsInput.java:38)    at
> org.apache.avro.tool.Util.openSeekableFromFS(Util.java:110)   at
> org.apache.avro.tool.DataFileGetSchemaTool.run(DataFileGetSchemaTool.java:46)
> at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:66)  at
> org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:55) 20/03/31 13:31:24 WARN
> util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your
> platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>
> {   "type" : "record",   "name" : "EventData",   "namespace" :
> "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging",   "fields" : [ {
> "name" : "SequenceNumber",
> "type" : "long"   }, {
> "name" : "Offset",
> "type" : "string"   }, {
> "name" : "EnqueuedTimeUtc",
> "type" : "string"   }, {
> "name" : "SystemProperties",
> "type" : {
> "type" : "map",
> "values" : [ "long", "double", "string", "bytes" ]
> }   }, {
> "name" : "Properties",
> "type" : {
> "type" : "map",
> "values" : [ "long", "double", "string", "bytes", "null" ]
> }   }, {
> "name" : "Body",
> "type" : [ "null", "bytes" ]   } ] }

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We were trying to use Apache Drill to query these Capture files as suggested in the MS documentation but ran into problems. We tried what you mentioned above to verify things but ran into the same error. For now, we abandoned the Capture feature and ended up writing our own capture consumer app to write out proper avro container files - apache drill works now but would like to understand if capture requires something special.

Comment: Sorry! I haven't solved it.

Comment: Just to add further confusion, Azure Stream Analytics can't read the Capture files natively either - you have to use a [custom deserializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-parsing-json) (see the Note section). One would think these capture files would be better supported by the other Azure services.